# Convert Object to Array Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object

```
{0: "item A", 1: "item B", 2: "item C"}
```

How can I convert the object to become array like this

```
[{0: "item A", 1: "item B", 2: "item C"}]
```

For now I have tried `Object.keys(obj)` but it returns each element in my object to array.

Really needs help. Thank you for helping

Comment: just enclosed the object in `[]`? like, `obj = [obj];`

Comment: thank you for replying. but what is the difference when i create a new empty array and push into it

Answer (score 8):

Just use bracket.

```js
let obj = {0: "item A", 1: "item B", 2: "item C"}
console.log([obj]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, there's an specific `Array` function for this matter: `Array.of`:

```js
console.log ( Array.of ( 1 ) )
```

This is more functional-friendly:

```js
const pipe = funs => x => funs.reduce( ( r, fun ) => fun ( r ), x )
const append = x => array => [ ...array, x ]
const sum = values => values.reduce ( ( r, value ) => value + r )

const result = pipe ( [
   Array.of,
   append ( 2 ),
   sum
] ) ( 1 )

console.log ( result )
```

Comment: @noorayu No problem